# how to display (test) .php file

Tags: php, html

I'm begin to learn php by my self, for example I have this code,suppose to disply "Hello World"

```
<html>
 <head>
  <title>PHP Test</title>
 </head>
 <body>
 <?php echo '<p>Hello World</p>'; ?> 
 </body>
</html>
```

I save it as hello.php, but when I open it by Firefox it display like that:

```
Hello World

'; ?>
```

can somebody explain for me?

Comment: You need to be running a server of some kind that interprets the php code

Comment: xampp is a popular free server. http://www.apachefriends.org

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Congratulations on getting started with php. 
You will need a web server to run PHP. Firefox can process HTML, CSS and Javascript markup/codes to output the web page but it can't process. It's a server side language and you will need some sort of server to do that.

If you have a Windows PC, the easiest way, at least for me, would be XAMPP/WAMP or similar software. You can find a good comparison chart in Wikipedia.

You can make the code clean with following syntax.

```
<html>
 <head>
  <title>PHP Test</title>
 </head>
 <body>
   <p><?php echo 'Hello World'; ?></p> 
 </body>
</html>
```

looks neat I think :)

Comment: A side note for the OP on why this code is "clean"... It's generally considered bad practice to have HTML markup in your actual data.  This is a small, contrived example (a "Hello World" application), so your "data" in this case is just a string.  But the idea is that you want your server-side code (PHP) to just manipulate data, and then surround that data with HTML markup.  The goal is to separate your data from your user interface, so you can reduce tight coupling between the two, making them more portable.

Answer (score 4):

Firefox is not able to interpret PHP code by itself. You will have to setup a local web server to run your code, and produce HTML, which could be read by Firefox.

Answer (score 1):

Congratulations on choosing PHP! With careful use it will give you years of coding pleasure.

Setting up a WAMP (Windows-Apache-MySQL-PHP) server 'stack' is a great way to get started - you are essentially running a web site from your own Windows machine.

Setting up is easy, but I imagine you'll be back here with follow up configuration questions - not a problem.

I would recommend [WampServer](http://www.wampserver.com/en/) or [Xampp](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp-windows.html) - WampServer is probably easier to set up.